# Visual Studio (Xamarin) randomly adds TextView controls to .xml files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

After I open the .xml file (layout), visual studio adds a textView control

any ideas?

visual studio adds this lines:

```
<TextView
android:minWidth="30px"
android:minHeight="30px"
xmlns="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
```

I tried to open with notepad++, everything is good.
Also, I tried to reinstall VS, and tried to open this project on my second PC, same thing.
I have two layouts (xml files), this issue is happend only with one of them, I tried to recreate him/change name, nothing helps..

Comment: Help -> Report a Problem

Comment: This bug appeared more than two years ago, I found some people who faced with the same issue, but all those questions closed without any helpful information, so I created this question in hope that maybe someone figured out why this bug happends

Comment: Could you tell me which version of visual studio you are using?

Comment: last one, 17.3.6 (release version)

Comment: I tried this version and didn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: What a strange thing, only one layout file causes this issue, https://pastebin.com/EkFyR8nM, another files works good.

Comment: You try to create several new layout files to see if the problem occurs.

Comment: I tried, the problem occurs only on this layout

Comment: You can try to lower the vs version or wait for the vs version update to see if this happens.